# Is there an idiom that means "I am compliant with the law/regulations"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "I am compliant with the law/regulations"? I can only think of "I am on the safe side", but it's too general, I am wondering if there's an idiom that's more specific to law and regulations in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call someone by the book, meaning they follow procedure, or the rules. Goody two-shoes could be used to describe a person who conforms to the rules, but it has a negative connotation. You wouldn't want to be called a goody two-shoes.

Answer (score 1):

There is an actual adjective for exactly that.

You are [**law-abiding**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/law-abiding).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : abiding by or obedient to the law
>   // *law-abiding* citizens